# OBD II Female connector with datasheet and measurements

Tags: connector, components, obd

I need an OBD II J1962 female port with 90 degree angled pins for pcb mount.

I am struggling to find a part which has a data sheet or enough info so I can create a pcb footprint for it.

Do you know where can I find one ?

So far I could only find these,

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/J1962-OBD-Female-Plug-with-90_60786542032.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.1.7048675a0b9stC
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/J1962-OBD-Female-Plug-with-90_60791426891.html?spm=a2700.details.deiletai6.1.3dc247fcjMT6mG

Comment: You mean you're struggling to find datasheets on Alibaba? Well, what a surprise.

Comment: @dimlostfaithinSE opened this question just to see if alibaba was involved, and if so, to say what you just said.  OP, you need a source that *doesn't* share your first name. Try Mouser, Digi-Key etc. *In fact, never shop at alibaba again. Nor any of the shops that sell out of their sh*tstream: AliExpress obviously, eBay, Amazon Marketplace, Banggood, DealExtreme etc*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I tried everything, this kind of connector is no where to be found or I can't seem to find it nowhere, all the other parts for the circuit even the male obd connector I could order from usual distributors.

Comment: I'm at disadvantage right now because I'm searching from Sweden and all the suppliers are optimizing for Sweden, but  Mouser, Digi-Key, RS, Galco, Grainger, McMaster-Carr are the first places you try. Or go the other way and identify top automotive electrical supplies like Delphi, and see who sells their stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one in the end which corresponds to the Ali Baba ones I guess.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32995602997.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.57625946RKQGWZ&algo_pvid=bf24b082-2e82-441a-b95a-63634e00eecb&algo_expid=bf24b082-2e82-441a-b95a-63634e00eecb-2&btsid=0b0a0ac215840532911565108e9f37&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: AliExpress is just single quantities of Alibaba.  Ali-*anything* is bad news, **[present company excepted, of course](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/present-company-excepted)**.

Comment: But I like this comment it is informative and funny :)

Comment: Alibaba was the only place I could find this kind of connector unfortunately. Do you have any advices ?